# Unable to run javascript function with AppleScript

Tags: javascript, applescript

I'm trying control video functions of a website by using applescript. The website has a flash video - jwplayer. In Google Chrome, I'm able to pause the video if I type in the command

`jwplayer('player_embed').pause();`

However, if I send in the command through AppleScript, it fails to work.

[image]

The console error message I get is as follows

[image]

And clicking VM4054:2 gives me this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is it an option to use Safari? This works...

```
tell application "Safari"
    repeat with t in tabs of windows
        tell t
            if URL starts with "https://www.jwp" then
                do JavaScript "jwplayer().pause();"
            end if
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: thanks! sorry i completely forgot to check this forum. yes! that does work in safari. however, i prefer chrome. i found a work around by using bettertouchtool to send the "spacebar" shortcut to chrome. however, it'd be nice to understand why the code isn't working in chrome. thanks so much though for answering.